# How to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in appium java?

Tags: appium-android

I have to perform login activity in appium for android application. But I am getting class not found error in my script. My application is opened in but after opening application login not performed.

```
public class AppiumTest2 {
    AppiumDriver driver;

    public  void setup() throws Exception  {
        DesiredCapabilities Capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        Capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "codeblaze");
        Capabilities.setCapability("platforVersion", "7.0");
        Capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Adnroid");
        Capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package name");
        Capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "activity name");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), Capabilities);


    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }


    public void LogInWithInvalidEmail() {
        //WebElement emailLoginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("lllogin"));
        //emailLoginButton.click();

        WebElement emailTextField = (new WebDriverWait(driver,60)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("etusername")));
        emailTextField.sendKeys("Invalid Email");

        WebElement passwordTextField = driver.findElement(By.id("etpassword"));
        passwordTextField.sendKeys("Random Password");

        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("lllogin"));
        loginButton.click();

    }

}
```

Actual Result: I am getting below error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

Expected Result: above mention error should not come and login activity should perform in application.

Comment: Do you have this dependency `'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'` in your gradle file?

Comment: No, i don't have this dependency in gradle. I have following code in build.gradle file:

Comment: apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the RCA was I was using appium-java Client from Reference libraries and Selenium-server jar from Maven Dependency section of my dev tool(Eclipse). That is causing sync in issue when driver is calling Java client to interact with Appium jar.

When I imported java client in my POM this issue resolved for me.

```
<dependencies>
    
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.1</version>
</dependency>

        
        
    
  </dependencies>
```